# подключить input checkbox + radio в одну функцию

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio

> на странице есть радиокнопка и чекбокс-при нажатии они должны вывести 1 общую картинку, можно ли их соединить в 1 функцию пробовала так писать,но не работает  $('input[type="checkbox", type="radio"]').click(function(){...
>
> html:

```
<input name="Лестница" type="radio" id="radio" value="слева" checked="checked" /> слева
<input name="Борт" type="checkbox" id="Bort" /> Борт у стены
```

> jquery:

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if($('#Bort').prop('checked') && $('#radio').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/bed_attic_2.jpg');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот работающий ответ:

```
$('input').on("click",function(){
    if($('#Bort').prop('checked') && $('#radio').prop('checked')) { 
      $('#image').attr('src','http://ecoskarb.ru/products/matrasy/img/bed_attic_2.jpg');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает!

Comment: Не за что. Только учтите, что этот метод запускается по клику на любой `input`. В идеале, нужным инпутам надо дать один класс и изменить `$('input').on("click",function()...` на `$('input.имя_класса').on("click",function()...`

Comment: хорошо,благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".tog").eq(0).on("change", function(){
  $(".image1").toggle(600);
    if ($(".tog").eq(0).is(":checked") && $(".tog").eq(1).is(":checked"))
  {
      $(".image3").toggle(600);

  }
});
$(".tog").eq(1).on("change", function(){
  $(".image2").toggle(600);
  if ($(".tog").eq(0).is(":checked") && $(".tog").eq(1).is(":checked"))
  {
      $(".image3").toggle(600);

  }
});
```

```css
body
{
font-family: sans-serif;
}
.image
{
  display: none;
background-color: #FFDD00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #C3A900;
  color:#7E6D00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height:100px;
  padding:0 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>
    Радиокнопка
    <input type="radio" value="Радиокнопка" class="tog">
  </label>
  <label>
    Чекбокс
    <input type="checkbox" value="Чекбокс" class="tog">    
  </label>
  <div class="image image1">
    200x100
  </div>
    <div class="image image2">
    200x100
  </div>
    <div class="image image3">
    200x100
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте им просто один общий класс.

```js
function checkProp(el) {
  if (el.prop('checked') === true) {
    $('.image').show(300);
    return;
  }
  
  $('.image').hide(300);
}

checkProp($('.openImage')); // Проверяем при загрузке

$('.openImage').on('change', function() {
  checkProp($(this)); // Раскрываем при изменении
});
```

```css
.image {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="openImage" name="Лестница" type="radio" id="radio" value="слева" /> слева
<input class="openImage" name="Борт" type="checkbox" id="Bort" /> Борт у стены

<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: когда выбрана радиокнопка должна появляться 1 картинка,при нажатии на чекбокс 2 картинка ,когда вместе нажаты-3 картинка